# SharePoint Online

Tags: sharepoint-2013, office365

I opted for a Office 365 trial version but unable to find any option related to sharepoint.office 365 has been incorporated with new UI not able to create site collection anybody have idea on how to create site collection in trial version of office 365 ?? any help would be appreciated

Answer (score 0):

When you first click on Sharepoint from portal.office.com, there should be a plus button saying 'Create Site' if you have the required privileges.

If you cannot see this button - try going to:

https://**YOURCOMPANY**.sharepoint.com/_layouts/15/online/SiteCollections.aspx

or

Go to Admin > Admin centers > Sharepoint from [portal.office.com](http://portal.office.com)

And try clicking the 'new' button under the site collections page.

Comment: Feel free to mark it as the correct answer. Just to let you know, there's also a stack exchange site for all Sharepoint questions http://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/